# symfony turbo-stream doesn't load in turbo-frame

Tags: symfony, turbo

I set up a project for test purpose, it works. But in another project, the above code doesn't work. The content of the turbo-stream appears in raw html and replaces the whole site.

```
//_parts/_dashboard_user_ranking.stream.html.twig

<turbo-stream action="update" target="the_frame_id" >
    <template>
        {{ include ("_parts/_dashboard_user_ranking.html.twig") }}
    </template>
</turbo-stream>
```

```
//index.html.twig

{% block body %}
{{ parent()}}

<main class="container row overflow-auto">
    <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="{{ path('app_dashboard_rankings',{period:'5jours'}) }}">5 jours</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('app_dashboard_rankings',{period:'3mois'}) }}">3 mois</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('app_dashboard_rankings',{period:'1an'}) }}">1 an</a>
                </li>
                {% for group in groups %}
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('app_dashboard_rankings',{period:'1an', groupID:group.id}) }}">{{ group.groupName }}</a>
                  </li>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </ul>

            <turbo-frame  id="the_frame_id"></turbo-frame>

    </div>
</main>

{{ include ("footer.html.twig") }}
{% endblock %}
```

And finally the controller :

```
 // classements seuls
    #[Route('/classements-{period}-{groupID}', name: 'app_dashboard_rankings')]
    public function classements(
        Request $request,
        FollowPointsRepository $followPointsRepository,
        string $period = '5jours',
        int $groupID = 0
     ): Response
    {

// ...
// ...
        $request->setRequestFormat(TurboBundle::STREAM_FORMAT);

        return $this->render('_parts/_dashboard_user_ranking.stream.html.twig',[
                'isUserInTop'=>$isUserInTop,
                'classement'=>$classement
            ]);
    }
```

As for the config, it is the same as in the test purpose project.